# Google Desktop hotkey Ctrl+Ctrl doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu, google-desktop

I recently installed Google Desktop Linux on my machine. The machine currently runs Xubuntu 11.04 (Natty).

It seems to be working fine, it shows up on the notification area (I don't know if this is the correct term - it shows up near the indicator plugin) and double clicking on it will open the Quick Search Box but the same box doesn't show up when I use the hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

Googling I found those two posts on Google Help Forums:

- [I'm having trouble installing Google Desktop over Xubuntu with xfce, what's wrong?](http://desktop.google.com/support/linux/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78330)

This one suggests that the packages `menu`, `menu-xdg` and `gnome-menu`. I assume the later must be a type for the package `gnome-menus` since there is no `gnome-menu` on my package list. All three packages are installed.

- [I press Ctrl twice but I don't see the Quick Search Box.](http://desktop.google.com/support/linux/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63283)

This time Google suggest a fix for KDE systems and to check if gdl_box is running. Gdl_box is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press and hold left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then press right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.